# Функции с переменным числом параметров

Tags: c++

Как передать переменное количество параметров `х` и `у` одной функции. Из этой задачи:

> Написать функцию (или макроопределение), которая определяет принадлежит ли точка с координатами (х , у) окружности с заданным радиусом R. Написать функцию
>   belong с переменным числом параметров, которая определяет сколько точек с координатами (х , у) принадлежат заданной окружности. Написать вызывающую функцию main, которая обращается к функции belong не менее трех раз с количеством параметров 3, 9, 11.

Cамо решение задачи не нужно.

Comment: мне интересно как передать переменное количество параметров х и у в одной функции

Comment: Вот это уже интересно. Отредактируйте вопрос, допишите. (А то закроют.)

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в том, как группировать `x` и `y`.

Мы можем засунуть их в структуру, например `struct Point { float x, y; };` тогда задача сводится к "как написать функцию принимающую переменное количество параметров". Это просто, для этого есть шаблоны:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

struct Point { float x, y; };

template<typename... T>
int f(const T&... args) {
    auto n = 0;
    auto R = 10;
    for (auto&& p : std::initializer_list<Point>{args...})
        if (p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y - R*R < 0.0001)
            ++n;
    return n;
}

int main() {
    f(Point{11, 12}, Point{22, 23});
}
```

Если же мы хотим передавать координаты последовательно, т.е. `f(x1, y1, x2, y2)`, то мы опять можем использовать шаблоны, но уже с рекурсией:

```
int f() {
    return 0;
}
template<typename... T>
int f(float x, float y, const T&... tail) {
    return int(x*x + y*y - R*R < 0.0001) + f(tail...);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если это задание из ВУЗа, то вполне вероятно, что ожидается что-нибудь подобное:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>  

int max(size_t number, ...)
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, number);
    int max = va_arg(argList, int);
    for(size_t i = 1; i < number; ++i)
    {
        int val = va_arg(argList, int);
        max = std::max(val, max);
    }
    va_end(argList);
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    int maxVal = max(6, 12, 43215, 61, 516, 412222, 65125);
    std::cout << "Max value is: " << maxVal << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В примере используется функция с переменным количеством параметров, где количество параметров задаётся первым. Решение предложенное @Abyx гораздо лучше, но есть и такое, которое унаследовано от C.

Comment: Ого, `va_list`! Да здравствуют динозавры! +1.

Comment: А почему только если ВУЗ-овское задание?  На практике  -- `va_list` тоже вполне удобный подход.

Comment: @avp, на мой взгляд, `va_list` проигрывает `variadic templates` по всем пунктам, поэтому я не вижу смысла использовать эти конструкции в современном C++

Comment: А на мой взгляд, современный С++ вообще не тот язык, на котором стоит писать практичные вещи.

Comment: Решение, предложенное @Abyx, хуже этого, если исходить из того, что мы тут решаем для чувака домашку.

Comment: @Shamov, вопрос состоит в том, как написать функцию с переменным числом аргументов. И, на мой взгляд, из двух вариантов, вариант Abyx лучше. Но знать полезно оба.

Comment: Понимать вопрос настолько буквально можно только в одном случае: когда цель состоит в том, чтобы дать такой ответ, который ожидает преподаватель. Но если цель такова, то `va_list` лучше. Про `variadic templates` в университетах скорее всего ещё не знают. Хотя я не уверен насчёт того, какой ответ ожидает преподаватель. Есть все признаки того, что он тот ещё тролль...

Answer (score 1):

Variadic templates здесь использовать не нужно. Шаблонная магия - это что-то вроде кунг-фу. Настоящие мастера не используют её без необходимости. Кроме того, в данной ситуации это было бы просто неправильно методологически. Количество параметров слишком велико, а тип у них один и тот же. Variadic templates существуют в языке определённо не для таких случаев. Для таких случаев существуют контейнеры и итераторы.

Приятным бонусом при использовании контейнера будет то, что функция для подсчёта элементов, удовлетворяющих некоторому условию, уже есть в стандартной библиотеке. Всё, что нужно сделать, это написать для неё обёртку, содержащую конкретное условие.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Point {
    float x, y;
    Point(float x_, float y_) : x(x_), y(y_) { }
};

template <typename It>
size_t belong(It first, It last, double r) {
    return count_if(first, last,
        [r](const typename It::reference itm) {
            return pow(itm.x, 2)+pow(itm.y, 2)-pow(r, 2) < 0.0001;
        });
}

int main()
{
    vector<Point> points;
    points.emplace_back(1.0, 1.0);
    points.emplace_back(2.0, 2.0);
    points.emplace_back(3.0, 3.0);

    size_t count = belong(begin(points), end(points), 10);

    // далее аналогично для 9 и 11 точек

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Задача состоит в использовании функции с переменным количеством аргументов, причём тут контейнеры?

Comment: Да, согласен. Задача сформулирована неудачно. Её формулировка подталкивает к неправильному решению проблемы, которая в ней же самой и изложена. Если бы преподаватель чуть-чуть подумал, то смог бы придумать более удачную задачу. Я в этом уверен.

Comment: Всё хорошо, но почему же `pow`? Оптимизаторы ещё не научились конвертировать `pow` в умножение.

Comment: @VladD А что не так с `pow`? Я исхожу из того, что во всех библиотеках реализация `pow` использует алгоритм Дейкстры для быстрого возведения в степень. В случае второй степени он делает только одно умножение.

Comment: @Abyx Я ничего сам не придумывал. В задаче, кроме неправильной подсказки, есть ещё и сама задача.

Comment: @Abyx Думаете, я не знаю? :)

Comment: @Abyx Название вопроса, очевидно, навеяно неправильной подсказкой из задачи :)

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, все три ответа имеют "право на жизнь", учитывая неконкретность вопроса и отсутствие постановки источника данных.

В контексте запрошенного языка, я, как и уважаемый Shamov, прежде всего подумал о STL. Потому как, в реальной жизни, пакет точек получался бы алгоритмически (ну например, из stdin), а не во время компиляции, что автоматически отметает первый и последний ответ. Соответственно, контейнер подходит лучше. Если вдруг embedded case, реализовать через передачу массива структур.

Если же, как ни странно, точки известны во время компиляции, можно шаблонами. Не забыть заплатить размером приложения.

Если реально вузовское задание, возможно преподаватель хочет увидеть va_list :)

Comment: Ещё есть вариант, что это вузовское задание с подвохом. Т.е. ответ c `va_list` будет засчитан, но это максимум четвёрка. А от реальных будущих программистов ожидается ответ в том ключе, что задача, которая предполагает 23 аргумента у функции (11 точек + радиус) просто абсурдна.

Comment: Это можно было оставить комментарием к другому ответу. Ваш "ответ" не содержит полезной информации.

Comment: @ixSci Содержит. Он апеллирует к тому, что данные становятся доступны лишь в рантайме. Это реально весомый аргумент. Изначально я об этом не подумал, а в ответе прочитал.

Comment: @Shamov, SO это сайт вопрос/ответ. Данный ответ не может быть принят в качестве правильного, т.е. он не отвечает на вопрос напрямую. Не надо пытаться устраивать тут форум - тут другой формат.

Comment: @ixSci Вы неправильно понимаете концепцию вопрос/ответ. Не так важно, правилен ли ответ в целом, и отвечает ли он напрямую на вопрос. Бывает так, что абсолютно неверный ответ содержит в себе интересную идею. Гораздо важнее то, полезен ли ответ хоть чем-то или вообще бесполезен.

Comment: @Shamov, я прекрасно понимаю концепцию SO. Нормальные ответы, которые отвечают на вопрос - получают плюсы, рассуждалки - минусы. Поэтому когда я из гугла прихожу на SO мне не надо 3 часа продираться сквозь тонны ответов. Если есть что добавить, но на ответ не тянет - пиши комментарий.

Comment: @ixSci Уверяю, вы понимаете концепцию неправильно. Ответы получают плюсы за то, что они полезны, и минусы за бесполезность. BTW, я комментарии в англоязычном SO никогда не читаю. И как раз потому, что там обычно бесполезные рассуждения. Всё полезное, как правило добавляется в ответ.

Comment: @Shamov Много узнал из Вашего обсуждения ) Спасибо. Мой ответ казался суммаризацией и дополнением уже данных ответов. Соответственно, непонятно какой из них я должен был комментировать. Кроме того, на тот момент я не мог оставлять комментарии )