# Функции с переменным числом параметров одинакового типа

Tags: c++, c++11

Как сделать так, чтобы в функцию можно было передавать переменное количество параметров **одного типа**?

Comment: вопрос хороший, но дубликат вот этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419928/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: У вас не очень точно заданный вопрос. Вам нужна именно шаблонная функция? Или обычная тоже сойдет?

Comment: @Harry особенно смущает заголовок вопроса. Т.е. автор уже как бы знает ответ.

Comment: @Alex.B в том вопросе в ответах различные типы, а не один

Comment: @erbber, ну так берите тот который подходит))

Comment: @Abyx вопрос уже пытались закрыть как дубликат, но в предложенном вопросе акцент на определенном типе, а тут же на любом, но одинаковом типе.

Comment: Читайте [man stdarg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html)

Comment: @avp `c++11` как бы намекает. Хотя, если бы я не изменил заголовок, Вы бы наверное этого и не предложили.

Comment: @alexolut, точно, не стал бы же я просто так писать, что искренне советую поменьше прикасаться к крестам (потом проблем будет меньше)

Comment: @avp впредь обращайте больше внимания на метки.

Comment: @alexolut, хотите сказать, что функции из `<stdarg.h>` не применимы в программах, компилируемых С++ компилятором?

Comment: @avp программа, компилируемая на C, является C программой, даже если она без изменений может быть скомпилирована на C++. Если в C++ есть механизм, заменяющий старый подход из C, то он должен быть использован как более безопасный и/или удобный. В частности, решение через `stdarg.h` не позволяет гарантировать однотипность передаваемых аргументов. Более того, чтобы хоть как-то указать на ожидаемые типы, нужно передать дополнительный параметр, который не будет совпадать с пользовательскими. Т.е. функция уже будет иметь разные типы аргументов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(std::initializer_list<T>)
```

Comment: это было бы норм, но надо `{}` ставить

Answer (score 6):

Возможное решение для любого кол-ва одинаковых типов, не требующее указывать фигурные скобки при вызове:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename... Types>
void foo(T t, Types... types) {
    for(auto&& e: { t, types... }) {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    foo("hello", ",", "world");
    foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    //foo(1, "hello"); // error
}
```

Comment: @Abyx действительно. Сейчас подправлю.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, с ошибкой компиляции если аргументы не совпадают:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class ...Args>
struct Dummy{};

template<class T, class ...Args, class = Dummy<typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Args>::value>::type...>>
void foo(const T &arg, const Args &...args){

}

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0;

    foo(i, i);      //ok
    foo(d, d);      //ok
    //foo(i, d);    //error
}
```